# How to access Unity Game Engine menu bar by keyboard shortcut?

Tags: unity

How to access Unity Game Engine top Menu bar by keyboard is there is any keyboard shortcut I could not find it on the internet

Comment: Please include a screenshot showing exactly which menu bar you mean. There are several!

Comment: https://ibb.co/bUQsxd
I am talking about this Menu bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bar in your image can be accessed by holding down the Alt Key (on Windows), then pressing whatever letter is underlined (e.g. the F will be underlined in File).

So, to access the file dropdown, you press Alt + F. Edit is Alt + E. This won't show up in Unity docs as it's an OS thing, not a Unity thing - most programs have this menu bar.

For Macs (and other OSs), you can find the equivalent shortcuts here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#General_shortcuts

Comment: That,s not what I am exactly looking for but It will get the job done Thank You for taking out your time and responding it cheers

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it has answered your question, in order to help others having a similar issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

Unity Documentation shows all shortcuts [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityHotkeys.html)

Comment: Thanks For taking out your time for responding but I can,t seem to find out the menu which I am looking for in Unity  documentation It is not present in Main Windows Section. Below is the link of Menu which I am asking for keyboard shortcut 
https://ibb.co/bUQsxd

Comment: I know which bar you mean, however, i don't think there are shortcuts for it. You could write some script on your own, but i think this is more a Mac thing instead of an unity think. Greetings!